# Using R/Shiny, automatically refresh dbGetQuery upon deadlock?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a (fairly complicated) Shiny app that is querying one of our SQL databases for data, then formatting that data as a series of ggplots. I intermittently get the following warning from Shiny: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Transaction (Process ID 62) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

I only get this error ~2% of the time. I believe I am getting deadlocked because I am querying data from a live system that operators are constantly updating. Basically, I think that means there's nothing I can do about the error.

I would like to program my app to detect the deadlock and automatically requery the data itself. (I could use validate to replace the error message with an instruction to manually rerun the query, but this is undesirable, since it requires manual intervention.)

Simplified app: (I think I've copied the relevant parts correctly, it's possible I'm missing a paren somehwere - the code obviously won't run for you regardless because I've redacted the SQL and you don't have my local ODBC connection set up.)

```
refreshintv = 600000

pool = dbPool(drv = odbc(), dsn = "[redacted]")

onStop(function() {
    poolClose(pool)
})

ui = fluidPage(
    dataTableOutput("df"),
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
    autorefresh = reactiveTimer(refreshintv)

    refresh = reactive({
        input$refresh #input$refresh comes from an action button that I haven't copied over for simplicity
        if("Auto Refresh" %in% input$options) {#input$options is similarly a checkboxGroupInput
            autorefresh()
        }
    })

    df = reactive({
        refresh()
        sql = "[insert sql code here]"
        df = dbGetQuery(pool, sql)
    })

}

app = shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

My first attempt was to try the following inside the df reactive:

```
while (!("data.frame" %in% class(df))) {
    df = dbGetQuery(pool, sql)
}
```

But I still get the deadlock error with the above code. It seems that as soon as shiny encounters the deadlock error, the reactive returns the error and the rest of the code is not evaluated.

My second approach was to create a reactive loop. I more or less knew this wasn't going to work, because df() changing causes refresh() to invalidate, even if class(df()) isn't changing.

```
refresh = reactive({
    input$refresh
    if("data.frame" %in% class(df())) {
        invalidateLater(1)
    }
    
    if("Auto Refresh" %in% input$options) {
        autorefresh()
    }
})
```

This, of course, does give an infinite recursion error: "evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?"

Everything I can find on error handling in shiny is basically just displaying error messages. How can I check for the deadlock error and get shiny to automatically refresh or invalidate df()? Is this even possible?

Comment: To minimize user interaction, you could try wrapping `dbGetQuery` with `tryCatch`, grep the error message for that deadlock, and attempt again. Realize, though, that if it happens repeatedly, your app may appear to lock up to the user. It might be advantageous to pursue an asynchronous model using `promises`.

Comment: Thanks. tryCatch is what I needed. I had found it during googling, but thought I had read that it didn't work with Shiny for some reason. The locking up is not an issue. It happens so rarely that it would be exceptionally rare for it to happen twice in a row. Besides which, any change to inputs takes about 2-10 seconds for the app to requery and then reprocess the data, so users are used to waiting on the app.

Comment: I wouldn't want to `tryCatch` *around* a reactive object, but I use `try` and `tryCatch` all the time in shiny apps. Actually, to be clear ... in functions that are used in shiny reactive objects. If you think about it, there are a lot of places `try`/`tryCatch` are used in regular R that to not be able to work in a shiny environment would be debilitating, creating in effect a different dialect of R.